Mi progreso en AndroidStudio no se ve en mi celular
He creado un proyecto en AndroidStudio, utilicé la plantilla "Bottom Navigation Views Activity" y dejé la configuración default que te da AndroidStudio, dejando el Lenguaje en "Kotlin".


Modifiqué el archivo "fragment_dashboard.xml" para agregar texto y verificar que puedo modificar cada sección que trae esta plantilla para posteriormente agregar imágenes, texto, botones, figuras, etc...
Agregué un texto al archivo y puedo ver en el visualizador que el texto sí se muestra, pero al correr la APP en mi teléfono no se muestra el texto que agregué, sólo se muestra un texto "This is dashboard Fragment".


Mi duda aquí es: ¿Porqué pasa esto?
¿Estoy editando el archivo incorrecto?
¿Necesito editar otro archivo para ver los cambios de la APP en mi celular?
Puede que yo esté cometiendo algún error muy obvio o algo por el estilo, pero no tengo mucha experiencia y quisiera saber si alguien sabe cómo puedo "agregar contenido" a mi APP.
Muchas gracias.
Y si, básicamente los archivos de la APP están intactos a como venía default, sólo agregué texto, pero les dejaré el código por si es necesario:
"fragment_dashboard.xml"
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_dashboard"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="XD LOL Superman"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
Y creo que esos serían los códigos más relevantes de la aplicación, o al menos eso pienso.

Hola. Tienes que cambiar el valor del TextView por programación, en el archivo que gestiona el fragmento. Si estás empezando con Android, te recomendaría que aprendas a usar Jetpack Compose. Entre otras cosas, podrás modificar con una facilidad pasmosa elementos de la interfaz gráfica. Y realizar además tareas hyper complicadas con mayor facilidad, como navegar de un sitio a otro, guardar el estado, diseñar interfaces gráficas complejas, etc.

Tienes que compilar la app cada vez que quieras aplicar los cambios. Ocurre cada vez que tocas el botón del triángulo. Lo hiciste?

Me parece que el problema se debe a que tu clase DashboardFragment no esta cargando el .xml adecuado, debes asegurar que esté "inflando" el layout fragment_dashboard.xml
Revisa en tu clase DashboardFragment, debe "inflar" fragment_dashboard.xml :
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)

